# How do I display large numbers such as thousand,ten thousand and so on?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, dosbox

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100
.DATA

    THOUSAND DW 1000
    HUNDRED DB 100
    TEN DB 10

    NL DB 0DH,0AH,'$'

.CODE
MAIN PROC

            MOV AX,@DATA
            MOV DS,AX
            
            MOV DX, 0
            MOV AX, 1332 
            DIV THOUSAND
            MOV BX, DX ;AX= 1,DX= 332
            MOV CL, AL ;AL=1
            
            ;DISPLAY FIRST DIGIT
            MOV AH, 02H
            MOV DL, CL  ;1
            ADD DL, 30H 
            INT 21H
            
            MOV AX, DX ;332
            DIV HUNDRED ;3.32
            MOV BL, DL ;AX=3,DX=32
            MOV CL, AL ;AL=3
            
            ;DISPLAY SECOND DIGIT
            MOV AH, 02H
            MOV DL, CL
            ADD DL, 30H 
            INT 21H
            
            ;FOR DISPLAYING THIRD AND FOURTH DIGIT
            MOV AH, 0H
            MOV AL, DL ;AL=32
            DIV TEN 
            MOV BX, AX ;BL=3, BH=2
            
            MOV AH, 02H
            MOV DL, BL              
            ADD DL, 30H 
            INT 21H
            
            MOV AH, 02H
            MOV DL, BH          
            ADD DL, 30H 
            INT 21H
            
            
            ;NEW LINE 
            MOV AH, 09H
            LEA DX, NL
            INT 21H
            
            MOV AX,4C00H
            INT 21H
            
MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```

I am using DOSBox emulator to write this program. As you can see, how can I display the number 1332 as a whole using the division method? My output doesn't seem to be correct as it displays 1351 instead. I would also like to know how to display numbers beyond 10000.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying numbers with DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904075/displaying-numbers-with-dos)

Comment: One problem is that you're using a byte-sized divide for 332, but 332 does not fit in a byte.

Answer (score 1):

> how can I display the number 1332 as a whole using the division method?

> ```
> MOV AX, DX ;332
> DIV HUNDRED ;3.32
> MOV BL, DL ;AX=3,DX=32
> MOV CL, AL ;AL=3
> ```

It is actually fine for your second division to be **byte-sized** (although the results from it will be in AL and AH instead of AX and DX), but it is your displaying of the first digit that **destroys the remainder from the first division** since you are using DL which is part of DX.
Below is one way how you could write it:

```
    THOUSAND DW 1000
    HUNDRED  DB 100
    TEN      DB 10
    
    ...
    
;DISPLAY FIRST DIGIT
    MOV DX, 0
    MOV AX, 1332 
    DIV THOUSAND  ; -> AX=1 DX=332
    MOV CX, DX    ; CX is a safe place
    MOV DL, AL
    ADD DL, 30h
    MOV AH, 02h
    INT 21h
            
;DISPLAY SECOND DIGIT
    MOV AX, CX    ; Restore 332
    DIV HUNDRED   ; -> AL=3 AH=32
    MOV CL, AH    ; CL is a safe place
    MOV DL, AL
    ADD DL, 30h
    MOV AH, 02h
    INT 21h
    
;FOR DISPLAYING THIRD AND FOURTH DIGIT
    MOV AH, 0
    MOV AL, CL    ; Restore 32
    DIV TEN       ; -> AL=3 AH=2
    MOV DX, AX    ; DH is a safe place
    ADD DL, 30h 
    MOV AH, 02h
    INT 21h
    MOV DL, DH          
    ADD DL, 30h 
    INT 21h
```

> I would also like to know how to display numbers beyond 10000.

The Q/A [Displaying numbers with DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904075/displaying-numbers-with-dos) explains that in great detail.